# Block Page while doing some actions

Tags: javascript

I have to block page, while system doing some action
For example, user clicks on a button, system start doing some long action and when it finishes page will refresh. 
I think it will be OK, if while system is busy, page should be blocked and user see some progress bar.

How can i do this using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you try out the following and let me know how it goes:

http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2012/04/23/how-to-close-sharepoint-modal-wait-screen-after-postback-when-page-is-in-dialog-mode/

hope it helps!

Comment: OK! I`ll try it

Answer (score 1):

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose()

Comment: Make answer usefull

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: i have no reputation for this :(

Comment: soo sad where are u from?

Comment: Russia, and you?)

Comment: from india whats up